# Azure worker role does not seem to start

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

We are building webapplication with an AngularJS frontend and a Web.Api backend. Both need to be hosted in Azure. To support this we created two projects:

- A worker role with an endpoint on 8080 for the web.api (converted from a selfhosting web.api)
- A web role on port 80

Both roles are combined in one azure service project. When running the project local in the azure emulator we have two endpoints that are working as desired. Localhost gives back the website, localhost:8080/api gives back the api. Together a nice website is running.

When deploying it to the staging environment on azure it publishes correctly. After done publishing, when we go to the site the sites loads up. The api does not work though.

When we go to the instances tab in the azure portal, we get 2 instances running in the project. 1 for XX.Azure.Worker_IN_0 and one for XX.WebRole_IN_0.

We looked in the eventlog of the worker role, but we cannot find any problems. Is there anyplace where we should look for errors? We tried searching for it but we couldn't find a log on the server. Or are we doing things with azure that we are not supposed to do.

Comment: What do you mean by the api does not work, connectivity or an error? Are you accessing from a corporate network and is there any chance that port 8080 is blocked by a firewall or is used internally for a proxy? If the roles are healthy and not recycling it indicates there's nothing wrong with your deployment. No reason Azure can't handle what you are trying to do.

Comment: The Web api project is nog working. Currently I test it at home and there is nothing being blocked. Though, still it gives a connection error on the Webapi url.

Comment: If you view the deployment in the portal (Dashboard in manage.windows.azure.com or cloud service properties in the portal) does it show an Input Endpoint [ipaddress]:8080?

Comment: I see for the worker role port 3389 and 8080 on the ip address and for he Web role I see port 80. And in the instances I see both instances on state running.

Comment: I'm out of ideas for the moment then. I think you've maybe gone about things the hard way; a web role is a vm running iis which will work equally well for the website and the api, in the same project if you wish, and a worker role is more like a vm running a windows service. That said, if you've got your code working in the local emulator I can't think of anything else which will stop you deploying it to Azure.

Comment: The worker role is a self hosting Webapi project. Maybe you have any pointers for me where to look for log files or something? Can't find anything stating what is going on..